# derivative of $(Z\alpha-Y\alpha X\alpha)^2$ with respect to $\alpha$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I want to calculate the derivative of this function and solve the gradient equation

$$f(\alpha)=(Z\alpha-Y\alpha X\alpha)^2$$

Where $Z,Y,X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha^T\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Hence all the products $Z\alpha,Y\alpha, X\alpha$ are scalar. So is $f(\alpha)$.

What I did was

$$\nabla_\alpha f(\alpha) = 2(Z-2Y\alpha X)(Z\alpha-Y\alpha X\alpha)=0$$
$$Y\alpha X=\frac{1}{2}Z$$

not sure how to proceed. Multiplying by a vector of ones?

Comment: Maybe this could help. https://atmos.washington.edu/~dennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf

Comment: When consulting the source provided by Vezen, be careful about which vectors are row vectors and which are column vectors. I'd advise rewriting everything as column vectors to avoid confusion. So like $u^T=\alpha$. Also your steps are confusing. Can you please explain with words?

Comment: Since most of us are not @greg we have to solve these questions in small steps ; so write $g(\pmb{a})=(\pmb{z}^T\pmb{a}-(\pmb{y}^T\pmb{a})(\pmb{x}^T\pmb{a}))$ and then write an equation for the differential of $g$ w.r.t. the differential of $\pmb{a}$. If you can do that the differential of $f(\pmb{a})=g^2(\pmb{a})$ is easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, let us rewrite all the vectors as column vectors (common convention) and using lower-case letters (also a common choice and easier to type):
$$
f(\alpha) = (z^T\alpha - y^T\alpha\, x^T\alpha)^2
$$
where $\alpha, x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Taking the gradient is fairly easy, just apply the chain rule a couple of times:
\begin{align}
\nabla_\alpha f(\alpha) &= 2(z^T\alpha - y^T\alpha x^T\alpha)\nabla_\alpha(z^T\alpha - y^T\alpha \, x^T\alpha)\\
&=2(z^T\alpha - y^T\alpha x^T\alpha)(z-\nabla_\alpha(y^T\alpha\, x^T\alpha))\\
&=2(z^T\alpha - y^T\alpha x^T\alpha)(z- y^T\alpha x - x^T\alpha y) \\
&=2(z^T\alpha - y^T\alpha x^T\alpha)(z- (x y^T + y x^T)\alpha).
\end{align}
Note that $xy^T$ and $yx^T$ are two $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ matrices and, in general
$$
xy^T + yx^T \ne 2 xy^T \ne 2 yx^T.
$$
Let us introduce the following matrices
\begin{align}
A &=  \begin{pmatrix} x & y\end{pmatrix} \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 2} &
B &=  \begin{pmatrix} y & x\end{pmatrix} \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 2} &
\end{align}
and note that $AB^T = xy^T + yx^T \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Then, we can rewrite the gradient as
$$
\nabla_\alpha f(\alpha)=2(z^T\alpha - y^T\alpha x^T\alpha)(z- AB^T\alpha).
$$

Next, even though you don't state it explicitly, it seems you're also interested in the stationary points of $f$, that is the points where the gradient is zero. In other words we'd like to find for which values of $\alpha$ we have
$$
(z^T\alpha - y^T\alpha x^T\alpha)(z- AB^T\alpha) = 0.
$$
This is only possible if the scalar $z^T\alpha - y^T\alpha x^T\alpha$ is zero or if so is the vector $z- AB^T\alpha$.

#### Case $z^T\alpha - y^T\alpha x^T\alpha=0$.

Besides the trivial solution $\alpha = 0$, this case is not straightforward as we need to solve a quadratic equation in $n$ variables. Apart from some special cases, the implicit equation of the solution space is all what we get (at least, I don't see other options at the moment).

> **Update:** This case does have a simple solution (see @greg's comment below):
> $$
> \alpha = \frac{z^T v}{x^T v\: y^T v}\,v\qquad\forall v \text{ such that } x^T v \ne 0 \text{ and } y^T v \ne 0. 
> $$

#### Case $z- AB^T\alpha=0$

When $n=2$ this is a simple system of two equations and two unknowns.

When $n > 2$, we can work this case out as follows. First, note that a solution exists only if $z$ is in the range of $A=(x\quad y)$, that is $z=ax + by$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. Then, assuming $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent, we can multiply both sides by the left inverse of $A$ and obtain
$$
AB^T \alpha = z \iff B^T \alpha = \bigl(A^T A)^{-1} A^T z.
$$
Now, note that we can't use the same approach again since $B^T$ is a fat matrix and, thus, it has no left inverse. However, we can use its right inverse matrix and write
$$
\alpha = B \bigl(B^T B)^{-1}\bigl(A^T A)^{-1} A^T z + P_B^\perp w
$$
where
$$
P_B^\perp = I - B \bigl(B^T B)^{-1} B^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}
$$
is the projection matrix onto the space orthogonal to the range of $B$ and $w$ is any vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Remark:**
We can rewrite everything as a function of $A$ only, as opposed to using both $A$ and $B$. Indeed, it is enough to notice that
$$
B = A J
$$
where
$$
J = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
is the $2\times 2$ inversion matrix. Then, after simple algebra,
$$
\alpha = A \bigl(A^T A)^{-1}J\bigl(A^T A)^{-1} A^T z + P_A^\perp w
$$
where
$$
P_A^\perp = I - A \bigl(A^T A)^{-1} A^T = P_B^\perp.
$$

You can even go further and express everything in terms of the vectors $x$ and $y$, but it doesn't seem to bring any additional insight.

Comment: $\tt+1\:$ Actually, the scalar case
$${
\def\a{\alpha} \def\l{\lambda}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
M = xy^T \qiq \a^Tz = \a^TM\a
}$$
has an infinite number of solutions, i.e.
for every vector $v$ such that $v^TMv\ne0$
$$\eqalign{
\a &= \left(\frac{v^Tz}{v^TMv}\right)v \;\equiv\; \l v
}$$

Comment: I didn't see this, thanks @greg ! I updated my answer to include your contribution.

Comment: @greg How did you derive the equation for $\alpha$ to be in this form?

Comment: @shani The form was an ansatz (aka a guess). The next step is to substitute it and see if you can make it satisfy the equation.